# How to extract required data from CURL response inside codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I tried to use the API from https://rapidapi.com/lambda/api/face-recognition-and-face-detection/details, and got the response as below

```
    {
"visualization": [
{
"image": "http://api.lambdal.com/nsuploads/6ed566063d/rawImages/09Feb21_153425_102613.jpg",
"entryid": "Face931873b7a3"
},

{
"image": "http://api.lambdal.com/nsuploads/6ed566063d/rawImages/09Feb21_152054_338756.jpg",
"entryid": "Face2e3921dee2"
}
],
"string": "<Album(6ed566063d) len: 4>",
    "name": "6ed566063d",
    "entries": [
    "Face931873b7a3",
    "Face2e3921dee2"
    ],
    "model": "<Model len: 4>",
        "size": 4
        }
```

And this is my controller:

```
public function viewAlbum($idx=null)
    {
        $id = $idx;
        if($idx == null || $idx == ''){
            redirect('Photo');
        } else {
            $dataAlbum = $this->admin->data_album($id);
            if($dataAlbum->num_rows() != 0){
                    $namaAlbum = $dataAlbum->row()->nama_album;
                    $albumKey = $dataAlbum->row()->kode_album;
                    $data['title'] = "Dashboard | FaceVoting Versi 1.0";
                    $data['getViewAlbum']= json_decode($this->cekAlbum($namaAlbum,$albumKey),true);
                    $view ='v_detailalbum';
                    $this->_template($data,$view);
            }else{
                redirect('Album');
            }
        }
    }

    private function cekAlbum($namaAlbum,$albumKey)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://lambda-face-recognition.p.rapidapi.com/album?album=".$namaAlbum."&albumkey=".$albumKey,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                "x-rapidapi-host: lambda-face-recognition.p.rapidapi.com",
                "x-rapidapi-key: 932571abf0msh45cf0f3cef74aacp19e151jsn33e9949a1974"
            ],
        ]);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
//          echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
            return null;
        } else {
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

I have tried this on my view:

```
<?= $getViewAlbum->visualization[0][0]; ?>
```

What i want is:
I want to display data visualization->image as image source , name, and model->size in page view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is JSON, you just need to use [`json_decode()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) like

```
$result = json_decode($response);
$result->visualization[0]->image;
```

OR to get array result instead of object

```
$result = json_decode($response, true);
$result['visualization'][0]['image'];
```